# Table in double column paper format

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, double-sided

I am writing a research paper in double column format but  the table is not fitting in the  format .
It looks like this [image]

My table is not displayed properly.
This is my code.

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
    \caption{Results}     
    \label{tab:table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Name} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Kannada} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Malayalam}\\
\cline{2-7} 
 & (P)\% & (R)\% & (F)\% & A & B & C\\
\hline 
Morfessor CAP &  48.07&60.39    &     53.53 & 47.25 &60.01  &52.88   \\
\hline 
  morpheme induction& 66.78 & 57.97  &  62.07  &60.33   & 59.55  &59.95  \\
\hline 

\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: If you want it to fit in the column, you need to either shrink it or rotate it.  You can also use table* to span more than one column.

Comment: How to do it? using which package?

Comment: no package is needed just use `table*` rather than `table` (and remove the `[h!]` option

Comment: graphicx (and adjustbox IIRC) support \scalebox \resizebox and \rotatebox

Comment: But with * it creates a large table in another page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the table's first column will become quite wide unless you let the words wrap. I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment, width set to `\columnwidth`, and the first column's type set to (a modified form of) `X`. Reducing the value of the parameter `\tabcolsep` by about half (from `6pt` to `3.5pt` and eliminating the whitespace to the left and right of the `tabularx` environment completes the job obtaining a fit without having to resort to more desperate measures, such a choosing a smaller font size.

I would also suggest you get rid of all vertical bars in the table and use the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` to get well-spaced horizontal lines.

The first horizontal line in the following screenshot is there just to illustrate the width of column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright}X}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of column

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Results}\label{tab:table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} Z *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule 
Name & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Kannada} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Malayalam}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7} 
& (P)\% & (R)\% & (F)\% & A & B & C\\
\midrule 
Morfessor CAP     &  48.07&60.39    &    53.53 & 47.25 &60.01  &52.88   \\ 
Morpheme induction& 66.78 & 57.97  &  62.07  &60.33   & 59.55  &59.95  \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: creates errors, ! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (Z): `c' used.See the array package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{tabularx}

Comment: Did you load the `tabularx` package and execute the instruction `\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright}X}`?

Comment: Yes. I have included the file in the directory and used using \include

Comment: @karu - `\include` -- *what*? You haven't confirmed whether you've run the `\newcolumntype` instruction. LaTeX will definitely choke on the code shown above unless you run that command.

Comment: Got the result, it is working fine